# How do I add body class on specific content_type who have specific field?

Tags: theming, 8

I need to add class in body when content type `article` and have image on it.
How do I achieve this?

I checked in `theme_preprocess_html` only found content_type as string. Don't know how to check image on it.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to do a little work in the html preprocess:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_html().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $variables['has_image'] = FALSE;
  if ($variables['node_type'] == 'article' && ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) && $node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
    $variables['has_image'] = empty($node->field_image->value) ? FALSE : TRUE;
  }
}
```

and the html template:

```
{#
/**
 * @file html.html.twig
 */
#}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html{{ html_attributes }}>
  <head>
...
  </head>
  <body{{ attributes.addClass(has_image ? ['has-image']) }}>
```

This will add the class `has-image` to the body tag of every Article type content node.

Comment: Thanks it works on normal fields. I just alter the solution. I uploaded mine just in case.

Comment: Little addition: for media files use: `$node->field_image->entity`

Answer (score 3):

In case you don't want to touch your template file.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_html().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['node_type'] === 'article') {
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    if ($node->field_image->getValue()) {
      $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'has-image';
    }
  }
}
```