# Check If field exists on node and perform action?

Tags: 10

How do I check to see if a field is being used on a node and if so, perform an action elsewhere on the page, such as moving a block or adding a body class?

Comment: Reasonable question, why the downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*How do I check to see if a field is being used on a node?*

```
$node->hasField($field_name)
```

*and if so, perform an action elsewhere on the page, such as moving a block?*

Configure multiple regions with different sets of blocks and then in a page template

```
{% if node.hasfield('field_image') %}
  {{ page.sidebar_second }}
{% endif %}
```

*or adding a body class?*

See [How do I add body class on specific content_type who have specific field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/212650/how-do-i-add-body-class-on-specific-content-type-who-have-specific-field)

In your case use `$node->hasField('field_image')` if you want to check for the presence of a field even if it is empty.

Comment: Thanks! Could this be modified to work for a paragraph field?

Comment: Yes, something like `node.field_paragraph.entity.hasfield('field_in_paragraph')`

Comment: So if my paragraph field was named 'field_image' and the field within it was named "banner" it would be like this?

node.field_image.entity.hasfield('banner')